# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when adding a count variable, works without?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am attempting to use JSON as a data-structure, to store values from an API, the end goal is to be able to call this data later and use it for other aspects of my platform. The current Issue is when I add a count variable to the list I am converting to a string and dumping to a json file I get the error, however when I completely remove the count variable and just dump the list it works fine until I try to decode it, I attempted to use lists because it was easier (in my opinion) to append data to this as it is a micro-service, yet I do understand that dictionaries are much more efficient but I cannot get those working either.

The code works, except when I add in the count variable e.g n = 0 | count = str(n + 1). In the code below there are a few vairables like throttle api etc those are defined above with static values that can be changes in a settings module i.e throttleApi = 30 (sec for the timer.sleep function) , and Token balances are also all defined.

```
def add_entry(count,balance_list, Token1_balances, Token2_balances, Token3_balances,localtime):

   # check if in seen set
   if (count,Token1_balances, Token2_balances, Token3_balances,localtime) in seen:
       return balance_list

   # add to seen set
   seen.add(tuple([count,Token1_balances, Token2_balances, Token3_balances,localtime]))

   # append to results list
   balance_list.append({'count':count,Token1: Token1_balances, Token2: Token2_balances, Token3: Token3_balances,'time':localtime})

   return balance_list


def write_to_json(lst, fn):
    with open(fn, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for item in lst:
            x = json.dumps(item, indent=4)
            file.write(x + '\n')


balance_list = []
seen = set()

if __name__ == '__main__':

  print('-'*40)   
  print(" Service Online and logging file has been established")
  print('-'*40)  

  n = 0 
  while True:
    time.sleep(throttleClient)
    localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
    minute = datetime.datetime.now().minute
    print('Local current time:',localtime,'CDT\n')
    if minute % throttleApi == 0:
     try:

        count = str(n + 1)
        balance_query   = p2p.getBalances()["result"]
        Token1_balances = str(balance_query[Token1])
        Token2_balances = str(balance_query[Token2])
        Token3_balances = str(balance_query[Token3])
        args1 = [count,Token1_balances, Token2_balances, Token3_balances,localtime]
        balance_list = add_entry(balance_list, *args1)  # add entry - SUCCESS  
        write_to_json(balance_list, 'balance.json') 
     except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print(ConnectionError)
        print('-'*20)
        print("Can't log balances due to connection error")
        pass
    else:
      pass
```

I had expected to get

```
{
    "count":"1",
    "BTC": "{'available': '0.00524973', 'freeze': '0'}",
    "ETH": "{'available': '0', 'freeze': '0'}",
    "1SG": "{'available': '15.57', 'freeze': '0'}",
    "time": "Sat Aug  3 16:08:04 2019"
}
```

and so on but I got either 1) that data above without the count 
 or 2)

```
  File "balance_logging.py", line 105, in <module>
    balance_list = add_entry(balance_list, *args1)  # add entry - SUCCESS
  File "balance_logging.py", line 56, in add_entry
    if (count,Token1_balances, Token2_balances, Token3_balances,localtime) in seen:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: I may also be doing this wrong, because the goal is to be able to load this data and iterate through it, however this data will create a few thousand records a day.

Comment: Your call to `add_entry` interchanges `count` and `balance_list`.  (Why does that function return anything, anyway?)

Comment: To be honest, I am new to python, not entirely sure why I returned the list there but it seemed to work, how would you approach it, by removing the returns?
I think I remember now, if you see lower in the code where I called write_to_json(balance_list,'balance_list.json')
I was attempting to avoid duplicate entries, however I still get the duplicates.

Comment: I have added the changes and it works, except for the count It is only logging "1" each time to the json file.

Comment: Sets can't contain lists.

Comment: I guess my real question comes from this sample response from the api I am dealing with:
`{'success': True, 'message': '', 'result': {'BNB': {'available': '0', 'freeze': '0'}}}`

I am attempting to store my json data in a similar manner with this data from the api I can iterate through result easily, however in my data I was attempting to use count as that mechanism but I fear I have this completely backwards, how would I approach this?

Comment: @FeatherBTC: The function mutates `balance_list` (in place), so it needn’t return anything at all (except the implicit `None` returned in Python when nothing else is, which the caller can and should ignore).

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling addEntry() you've swapped balance_list and count.  Thus you're trying to see if your big tuple is in the set 'seen', you're hashing a tuple with a list in it.  But since lists are mutable and not allowed to be a part of the keys to sets and dicts you get the error you're seeing.